# cv2 video to array of images

Tags: arrays, opencv, video-capture

I am using cv2.VideoCapture and cv2.imwrite to convert a video into an image sequence in Google colab using this:

```
import cv2
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')
def getFrame(sec):
    vidcap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC,sec*1000)
    hasFrames,image = vidcap.read()
    if hasFrames:
        cv2.imwrite("image"+str(count)+".jpg", image)     # save frame as JPG file
    return hasFrames
sec = 0
frameRate = 0.5 #//it will capture image in each 0.5 second
count=1
success = getFrame(sec)
while success:
    count = count + 1
    sec = sec + frameRate
    sec = round(sec, 2)
    success = getFrame(sec)
```

Instead of writing each image to my session files, how would I add each image to a frames[] array that could be further processed?

Comment: You may start with an empty list: `frames = []`, and use `frames.append(image)` (assuming you have enough RAM).

Comment: @Rotem I'm using colab pro, so I had enough RAM. However, I decided against this and went for the original code. I'm a video producer and beginner developer, so I'm still learning python. Thanks for the suggestion!